# How to add my class to my defined custom field in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a created a custom field named "brandtext" in the menu link, I want to apply css to each field brandtext
like

```
brandtext:my text1
class:class1
brandtext:my text2
class:class2
brandtext:my text3
class:class3
brandtext:my text4
class:class4
```

I will define these these classes in my css.
How can I proceed?

Comment: overiding field template is one way ,any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

You could get menu tree with `menu_tree_all_data` and crawl it your self, print menu items the way you need.

```
  $tree = menu_tree_all_data('menu name']);
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7.x

After getting menu tree you can call:

```
   menu_tree_add_active_path($tree);
```

so it will add active class to menu item of currently viewed page. That function is part of menu block module, so you have to install it in order to use this function.

http://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!menu_block!menu_block.module/function/menu_tree_add_active_path/7.43